# Hard Drive not recognized outside bios

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

This is Ubuntu related. Bear with me.

I built a new machine using Windows 10 after a failing Windows 7. The C drive from Win7 was recognized at first in Win10 as an F drive (new C drive of course). Then a "fix error" notice made it disappear. It would appear in the bios, but disappear in Windows. Returning to the bios it was gone. It would only reappear if I shut down the machine and change SATA ports. Again, it would return in the bios, but disappear after loading Windows.

It was suggested I try an "out of Windows environment." So Ubuntu it is. Always wanted to try Linux. I installed Ubuntu on a standalone drive. Upon plugging in the old drive...same thing. Drive appears in the bios and never makes it to Ubuntu. Further, it disappears from the bios if I restart just like in Win10. Only if I power down and choose a new port does it return to the bios, but then disappears again after loading Ubuntu.

I also tried an external USB dock in both Win10 and Ubuntu with no luck.

Any suggestions to access it short of a recovery service?

Edit: "appear in the bios" means that if I enter the UEFI bios by way of F2/Del, the drive will appear in the list of internal drives. Once Windows or Ubuntu are loaded, the drive does not appear in Win Explorer nor Ubuntu Nautilus. If I restart and enter the bios again by way of F2/Del, the drive will no longer appear in the list of drives in UEFI bios unless I completely shut it down and change the port of the SATA cable. Then the cycle repeats.

Haven't checked smartctl, but will.

Comment: Please edit your question to be completely clear what you mean by "appear in the bios"

Comment: BIOS reads the drive-parms stored in chips on the drive, but not the drive mechanics (where data is stored).  It could be the drive electronics are fine, but the mechanics (drive heads, platters etc) are dead or unusable, hence BIOS doesn't detect issues, but a real OS that wants to use the drive sees nothing but problems & ignores it.  Have you checked your drive status (`smartctl`) to see the status yourself?